# Полиморфизм при возврате значений из функции

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

У меня есть несколько классов для реализации денежных операций:

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
#define MONEY_H

#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using std::string;


class Money;

class Expression
{
public:
    virtual Money reduce(const string& to) const
    {
        assert(false);
    }
};

class Dollar;

class Money : public Expression
{
public:
    Money(int amount_, string currency_);

    static Money dollar(int amount);
    static Money franc(int amount);

    string currency() const;
    Money times(int value) const;
    Money reduce(const string& to) const;

    bool operator==(const Money& money) const;
    Expression operator+(const Money& right) const;
public:
    int amount;
    string currency_;
};

class Bank
{
public:
    Money reduce(const Expression& source, const string& to) const;
};

struct Sum : Expression
{
    Sum(Money augend, Money addend)
        : augend(augend), addend(addend) {}
    Money reduce(const string& to) const
    {
        return Money(augend.amount + addend.amount, to);
    }
    Money augend;
    Money addend;
};

#endif
```

Но я не знаю, как использовать полиморфизм при возврате значений из функций. Полиморфизм работает для ссылок и указателей, но из функции reduce результат возвращается по значению.

Здесь есть базовый класс `Expression` для выражений и частные случаи выражений: `Money` - атомарное выражение и `Sum` - выражение "сумма". Функция reduce должна возвращать значение типа Money. Как сделать это при помощи полиморфизма?

PS. Пример из книги, в которой используется Джава, а в джаве везде ссылки.

Comment: Пллиморфизма "по значению" не бывает. Как ни вертите, возвращать придется указатель или ссылку. Можете завернуть его во что-нибудь: умный указатель, pimpl и т.п. но суть остается той же.

Comment: Я знаю, что полиморфизма по значению не бывает. Но надо как-то выкрутиться, ведь это не ява, где все передается и возвращается по ссылке.

Comment: Указатели ваше все. + Вы возвращаете объект, который сделан на стеке, это опасно.

Comment: Тогда как заставить работать такой код? unique_ptr<Money> Money::reduce(const string& to) const
{
 return make_unique<Money>(this);
}

Comment: Если вы собираетесь возвращать `this` - то уж это можно делать и ссылкой, и указателем, без всяких `unique_ptr`...

Comment: наверное создавать класс handler, содержащий указатель

Comment: Вместо абстракции «Money» введи абстракцию «Валюта» и сделай все её конкретные реализации (как «Dollar») синглтонами... всё встанет на свои места и без проблем можно будет возвращать обычные указатели...

Comment: Может std::shared_ptr? https://onlinegdb.com/SJ3SV82rG

Answer (score 1):

1.Как Вам уже подсказали выше, Вам нужен абстрактный базовый класс, и классы-наследники для конкретных реализаций. При возврате из функций, Вы можете возвращать указатель на базовый класс Money.
В примере ниже указатель типа базового класса в одном случае указывает на класс Dollar, во втором случае, на класс Franc :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Money
{
public :
    Money(int x) : amount(x) {}
    virtual ~Money() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
protected :
    int amount;
};

class Franc : public Money
{
public :
    Franc(unsigned x = 0) : Money(x) {}

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "it's " << amount << " francs" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public :
    Dollar(unsigned x = 0) : Money(x) {}

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "it's " << amount << " dollars" << std::endl;
    }
};

Money* WhatIsIt(Money* m)
{
    m->print();
    return m;
}

int main() {

    Money *a;
    Dollar dl(5);
    Franc fr(10);

    a = WhatIsIt(&dl);
    a = WhatIsIt(&fr);

    return 0;
}
```

2. > Expression operator+(const Money& right) const;

Не забудьте, что если Вы собираетесь писать функции для операций с разными валютами типа сложения, Вы не можете просто складывать между собой их значения : это логически неверно, так как валюты имеют разное соотношение между собой. Как минимум, вам понадобится выбрать одну в качестве универсального эквивалента и для всех остальных написать оператор приведения типа к этой валюте.